# Periodic autoremove

Tags: apt, kernel

Relatives have a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04, which automatically updates its software. After a few months, they are faced with a full root partition and can no longer start XServer (among other things).

Looking into this they had about 10GB of old kernel files laying around.
So step

1. for me was to purge `linux-generic` and set `linux-image-generic` as manual, as without it you loose all the kernel headers which you do not need on that machine.
2. I set autoclean from 0 to 14 days so at least downloaded packages get cleaned up again.

What I am missing now is a step 3, where I could periodically tell the system to not only do a autoclean but also a autoremove and get rid of all non-used kernel packages.

Is there such a thing or do I have to hack something together manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

from

```
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";
```

to

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```